# Preventing duplicate requests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronization

We have a Rails API with the following API call

```
POST /book
  user_id (integer): The user id to book the class for
  class_id (integer): The id of the class to book
```

In this call, we send out a request to a third party API to book the class. The problem is we want to guarantee that duplicate requests for a (user_id, class_id) pair aren't sent. We could prevent users from clicking on the book button multiple times but we want that extra level of protection. We don't want duplicate charges on our hands.

Any ideas how we can enforce something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an new model called `Booking` with an associated database table and then create a new booking whenever this post request occurs. To make sure that no previous bookings exist, you can validate uniqueness in your model like so:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :class_id
```

If creating a booking fails in the controller, then you know that a booking already exists and can return a message to that effect.